# Numpy shape not including classes

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I want to create a dataset(data.npy) that has the same format as cifar10. The sample omniglot dataset contains

```
 data = [0001_01.png,0001_02.png,0001_03.png,0001_04.png,0002_01.png,0002_02.png,0002_03.png]

 class_name,filename = data[0].split('_')
```

Each file is append with class.There are 1600 classes and each class has 20 samples. The expected dataset(data.npy) shape is (1600,20,784)

But the shape i got is (1,20,784). Below given is the snippet

```
classes = []
examples = []
prev = files[0].split('_')[0]
for f in files:
   cur_id = f.split('_')[0]
   cur_pic = misc.imresize(misc.imread('new_data/' + f),[28,28])
   cur_pic = (np.float32(cur_pic)/255).flatten()

   if prev == cur_id:
      examples.append(cur_pic)
   else:
      classes.append(examples)
      examples = [cur_pic]
      prev = cur_id
np.save('data',np.asarray(classes))
```

Any suggestions would be greatly helpful. The above code is taken from https://github.com/zergylord/oneshot

Comment: I'd suggest examining `np.array(classes)` before saving.  What's its `shape`, `dtype`.  If `dtype` is object, look at the type, shape, size of some its elements.

Comment: In Python, `class` has special meaning.  In your code it is just the name of a variable.  Using that word in the subject can be confusing.